# How to differentiate between regular and irregular verbs

Tags: past-participles, history, irregular-forms

As I know that in regular verbs we put 'ed' and in irregular verb we do not put 'ed' while changing it into the past or past participle.

But for anyone who does not know about the 2nd and 3rd form of verb, how should he/she know that word is a regular or irregular verb?

Comment: What is it that you call the “2nd and 3rd form” of verbs? Verbal forms don’t generally have numbers …

Comment: Probly past and participle: _go, went, gone; be, was, been; have, had, had; walk, walked, walked;_ etc.

Comment: I asked you about those numbers in an earlier question as well, user78248... But to know whether a verb is regular or not, you can consult a dictionary. Most of them do mention the base forms of verbs.

Comment: There's no way of knowing whether *forget* becomes *forgetted* or *forgot/forgotten* without **learning** that (or looking it up) -- there's nothing in the verb itself which dictates it. And analogy with *get* doesn't completely help in BrE, which doesn't have *gotten*.

Comment: This is the problem that occurred many times in my teaching life, students always ask me what is the trick to know whether the verb is regular or irregular

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning the very most rudimentary rules of basic English and therefore belongs on ELL instead, ***not*** on a site devoted to professional linguists, etymologists, and serious language enthusiasts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is highly irregular for this site.

Answer (score 5):

Good question. The answer is that ***irregular*** means 'not following the rules'.

In this case, the "rules" are for the ***regular*** verbs, and they say

1. The past form and the participle form of regular verbs are the same
   (i.e, "2nd form" = "3rd form")
2. These forms of regular verbs add "-ed"
   (sometimes spelt differently).

So irregular verbs must violate those rules, which means **either**

1. they don't use "-ed", **or**
2. they have three forms instead of two.

Any dictionary will give the forms of a verb, but only in code. Here's the key:

1. if the dictionary indicates that the past form is "-ed", or "-d" or "-t",
   or if it's a special form like *spent*, where "d" changes to t,
   or if there is no participle form given,
   then it's **regular**
2. if the dictionary gives three forms (like *sing, sang, sung*),
   or no verb form ends in "d" or "t" (like *wear, wore, worn*),
   then it's **irregular**.

Plus, there are very few irregular verbs, and they follow common patterns, and they occur often.
Which means you can learn them from [a list, like this one](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/irregverbs.pdf).

Comment: Thnx for this, I will try this method to make my students understand about regular and irregular verbs

Comment: One thing I didn't mention; regular verbs are sometimes called "weak verbs" and irregular "strong". Then there are "irregular weak verbs", like _spell, spelt, spelt_ that don't have three forms, but use an irregular allomorph of the regular past morpheme. The distinction is clearer in German, where all strong verbs have a past participle form ending in "-en"(_singen, sang, gesungen_), while all weak verbs have a past participle form ending in "-t" (_meinen, meinte, gemeint_). Marking is very useful in inflected languages.

Comment: This seems an extreme simplification. Claiming English has 200 patternlessly irregular verbs is like claiming 900 in Spanish. Neither is useful. Apart from verbs subjected to suppletion (*be*, *go*), almost all verbs called “irregular” in a simplistic or synchronic analysis become [***“differently regular”***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb#English) in a broader or diachronic one, where other, more subtle patterns appear. That native speakers are passively aware of these deeper patterns can be shown in the creation of new strong verb inflections like *dove* and *snuck*.

Comment: Of course that's true. However, I suggest that this is way too complicated for kids being introduced to English grammar. Especially if they're not native speakers; native speakers have all soaked this up and don't need lists, only correct description.

Comment: Thnx for ur this great information it will help me

Comment: From the user’s final comment, I can see that you were quite right after all.